# SQL Query to group dates by month

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have a database with 3 tables:

1. `mothlist([number],[name])`
2. `temp_subs([sub_id],[date_created],[expiry_date])`
3. `temp_orders([order_id],[sub_id],[order_date])`

I am trying to write a query to get the total counts expiry date and order for the current year grouped by month.

The query I have now is:

```
SELECT 
    monthlist.name 'Month',
    count(temp_subs.expiry_date) 'Expiry Date',
    count(temp_orders.order_date) 'Order Date'    
FROM 
    monthlist  
    FULL JOIN temp_subs 
    on 
        monthlist.number = datepart(month, temp_subs.expiry_date) and 
        datepart(year, temp_subs.expiry_date) = year(getdate())
    FULL JOIN temp_orders 
    on 
        monthlist.number = datepart(month, temp_orders.order_date) and 
        datepart(year, temp_orders.order_date) = year(getdate())
GROUP BY monthlist.number ,monthlist.name      
ORDER BY monthlist.number
```

If someone could tell me what am I dong wrong here I would be very grateful.

Comment: What is wrong now? Too many rows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A double join means that every temp_sub is repeat for every temp_order.  One way to avoid double-counting is adding  a `distinct` on a unique column.  If the tables have a primary key called `id`, that could look like:

```
SELECT monthlist.name 'Month'
  ,count(distinct temp_subs.id) 'Expiry Date'
  ,count(distinct temp_orders.id) 'Order Date'
```

Comment: Thanks Andomar for yout quick reply, but adding 'distinct' does not work. If I do a LEFT JOIN instead of full and leave only one of them then the totals are correct. Now I'm trying to find a way to have both joins

Comment: You've got to add `distinct` on a unique column, like `id`.  Then it will work.

Comment: Thank You. Distinct ID fields and left join Works perfectly